# selecting 0776578969 from database and displaying 0776 578 969

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

trying to display data with space from database (ms-access) eg selecting 0776578969 and displaying 0776 578 969 using access and vb. Help

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: am selecting a phone_no from database and trying to display it in a datagridview column with space in it but i don't know how to use the 'space' function

Comment: You need to do ordinary string manipulation using `Substring`.

Comment: how do i use substring when am selecting the string from the database and displaying it in a datagridview

Comment: You might need to do some research into number grouping, which is likely dependent on your territory (where is the territory for this number?). Do you always want the format 4-digits, 3-digits, 3-digits? Also, decide whether you need to handle +xx international prefix numbers, which will need to be handled another way.

Answer (score 3):

If you need this in a report or form, then just use custom format.

(in the format setting just go:

@@@@ @@@ @@@

And, in code, you can go:

Format("your value","@@@@ @@@ @@@")

Access is a business application development tool, and such types of string processing and having to use VBA code is not required for common formatting in reports, forms.  And even as above shows, for code you don't process using mid$ etc, but use formatting command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to perform this in MS Access, then you will want to review the [`Left`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/left-function-HA001228873.aspx), [`Mid`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/mid-function-HA001228881.aspx) and [`Right`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/right-function-HA001228900.aspx) function.  Here is a sample query that should give you the results you want:

```
Test Table:
PhoneNumber
776578969
123456789

SELECT Left(test.phonenumber, 3) & " " & Mid(test.phonenumber, 4, 3) & " " & Right(test.phonenumber, 3)
FROM test;

Results:
776 578 969
123 456 789
```